# Undo consecutives convertTo operations

Tags: c++, opencv

When applying this to a `cv::Mat`

```
original.convertTo(new_image, -1, 1.2, -10);
```

How can I implement the opposite effect, to get back my original matrix?

I've tried lowering the scale parameter below 1, and inverting the beta parameter without getting desired effect.
I think I am missing something about how they works, but can't find out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?mat-convertto#mat-convertto) functions computes:

```
 new_image = original * alpha + beta
 new_image = original * 1.2   + (-10)
```

To get the inverse operation, you need to:

```
 old_image = (new_image - beta) / alpha;
 old_image = (new_image - (-10)) / 1.2;
```

Please **note** that the results may be `saturated_cast<>`'ed to fit the matrix type. In this case the operation is not reversible and produces an image different from the original one. This is very likely to happen for `CV_8U` matrices, but not for `CV_64F` matrices.

This is a simple snippet to shows how it works:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat original = ...

    double alpha = 1.2;
    double beta = -10.0;

    Mat new_image;
    original.convertTo(new_image, -1, alpha, beta);

    // // Revert the 'convertTo'
    Mat old_image;
    old_image = (new_image - beta) / alpha;

    // Check the difference
    Mat diff;
    absdiff(original, old_image, diff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I had indeed missed something about how convertTo works. Nevertheless, I don't get exact original image by applying this. My undo'd is strangely a bit darker than original. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, when you use `convertTo` there is a `saturated_cast<>` involved. That means, for example, that if you have a `CV_8UC1` image (with values `[0, 255]`), every value that exceeds 255 is saturated to 255. So when you convert back the result is a darker. Take a look at the "Please note... " part in my answer

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't understood this point at the beginning. Much clearer now ! So, I don't have any other choices than keeping in memory previous images, that's a shame, but totally logic, when this saturation point is understood. Thanks again !